# CSS - div height calculation without "calc"

Tags: css, height, calc

In my website, I am using two divs that should have their `height` like [in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwb7j.png).

So, there is a `div` with `height:90px;` that is aligned to the bottom of the window, now what can I do if I want the 2nd div (red) to "fill" the rest of the window? Red `div` should have the `height` of the window minus the `height` of the blue `div` but something like `calc(100vh - 90px)` wouldn't work, right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually `height: calc(100vh - 90px);` **does** work

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
footer {
  height: 90px;
  background: blue;
}
main {
  background: red;
  height: calc(100vh - 90px);
}
```

```html
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
```

However, it's not entirely clear how you want this to react if the content would normally cause vertical scrolling. *Then* this is not the answer, probably.

**Alternative solution with `flex-box`**

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap:no-wrap;
  min-height:100vh;
}
main {
  background: red;
  flex:1;
}

footer {
  flex-basis:90px;
  flex-shrink:0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <main>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </main>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh thanks. That's weird, no clue what I did wrong earlier but it didn't work with calc before.

Comment: If the content does overflow then the main section just needs to be set to scroll and this answer will work fine. `main {overflow-y: scroll;}`

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this can be done without using javascript to get the window height.

So, I'd use some javascript to get the window height, and then change the height of the top element accordingly (assuming a static footer).

**HTML**

```
<div class="top" id="top">
</div>
<div class="bottom"> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.top{
    background-color:red;
}
.bottom{
    height: 90px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var h = window.innerHeight;
document.getElementById("top").style.height = (h - 90) + "px";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n5aLt5y6/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried this too and it worked! It's probably a better solution since "calc" is not supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you cannot use `calc` in your project; please consider using the following JavaScript in order set the height of your first div.

How does it work:

- Second DIV (footer) is positioned from the bottom using simply CSS `bottom:0;`
- First DIV height is adjusted by JavaScript when window `load` or `resize`.

https://jsbin.com/lunitafuja/1/edit?html,output

```
<style>
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #a {
        top: 0;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: red;
        width: 100vh;
    }

    #b {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: blue;
        width: 100vh;
        height: 100px;
        bottom: 0;
    }
</style>

<script>
    window.app = {
        start: function () {
            var bTop = Math.round(document.getElementById('b').getBoundingClientRect().top);
            var a = document.getElementById('a').style.height = bTop + 'px';

        }
    };

</script>
```