# Can't stick my footer to the bottom when editor autoresize

Tags: html, css

I have a vertical navigation bar to the left with a position set to fixed and footer is included at the end of every page.

When my wysiwyg editor (TinyMCE) autoresize footer is hanging.

Image:

[image: Footer hanging]

How do I avoid this?

Code:

```
/* page.php */

<?php require(ABSPATH . 'header.php'); ?>

some content ...

<?php require(ABSPATH . 'footer.php'); ?>

/* header.php */

<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

<div id="header">
</div>

<?php require(ABSPATH . 'menu.php'); ?>

<div id="content-wrapper">

/* menu.php */

<div id="left-menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="menu-title">
            <a href="#">Title</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

/* footer.php */

</div><!-- close content wrapper -->

<div id="footer">
***FOOTER***
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* menu */

#left-menu {
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    background: #000;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
}

/* menu style */

#left-menu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#left-menu li {
    text-indent: 15px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

#left-menu li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

#left-menu li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

/* menu title style */ 

#left-menu ul .menu-title {
    line-height: 45px;
}

#left-menu ul .menu-title { 
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#left-menu ul .menu-title {
    color: #999999;
}

#left-menu ul .menu-title a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}

/* content | header | footer */

#content-wrapper {
    margin-left: 200px;
    padding-top: 12px;
}

#header {

}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right:0;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: What is your HTML code?

Comment: Yeah, this looks like a float issue.  What happens if you clear the float?

Comment: @crazymatt It's in the post now look at the section code.

Comment: @Aarmora Footer will be underneath my content and not at the bottom.

Comment: @madsen Would this question help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31268717/css-div-height-calculation-without-calc/

Comment: If you have a fixed left navigation and you want it to stop before it shows up over the footer (or any other element for that matter) you will need to do this using JQuery. If you decide to ever use the [bootstrap framework it comes built in](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy).